# CakePHP returns empty response when called by emberjs

Tags: rest, cakephp, ember.js

I'm trying to setup some REST API end points in a CakePHP 2.3 app.  I've tried using several methods of outputting the json.  It works when I hit the url with a browser, however the calls being made by the EmberJS RestAdapter fail, responding with an empty response body. Here are my current controllers.

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class VcrAppController extends AppController {
    public $viewClass = 'Json';


}


App::uses('VcrAppController', 'Vcr.Controller');

class DestinationsController extends VcrAppController
{
    public $uses = array('Vcr.Destination');

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('index');
        $this->Auth->allow('view');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $destinations = $this->Destination->find('all');

        $this->set(array(
            'destinations' => $destinations,
            '_serialize' => array('destinations')
        ));

    }

    public function view($destination_id)
    {
        $destination = $this->Destination->findById($destination_id);
        $this->set(array(
            'destination' => $destination,
            '_serialize' => array('destination')
        ));
    }
}
```

I suspect this has something to do with the request handler.  I've tried several different implementations, including mapresources and parseextensions, and modifying emberjs to append .json to the urls.  Not quite sure where to go from here.

Comment: is the url used by ember.js right?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the RequestHandler component at all? In the AppController? I don't see it in both controllers you've pasted.

Did you check http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html?

Also, did you check your log folder? Is debug set to 2?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem. My assumption then is that you had the same cause, though you did not say it: the client Ember JS and the CakePHP server were on different domains (e.g. client was local and server was already hosted).

The fix is to add this:

```
$this->response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

to your controller actions that you want to access for your API. There might be a better way to make this is the default, app-wide, but I know of none yet. Hope this helps.

EDIT: Be aware that the * means that any domain can access the API call -- which may well be what you want, but if not, simply specify the domains you *do* want allowed instead.